# Drawing rectangle line-by-line doesn't have the same result as drawing it directly

Tags: qt, qtableview

I'm trying to customize the borders of the cells in a (custom) `QTableView`. To do that, I found [this](https://forum.qt.io/post/510667):

```
class MyDelegate : public QItemDelegate {
  public:
    MyDelegate( QObject *parent ) : QItemDelegate( parent ) { }
    void paint( QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index ) const {
      QItemDelegate::paint( painter, option, index );
      if( /* some condition */ ) {
         painter->setPen( Qt::red );
         painter->drawRect( option.rect );
      }
    }
}
```

This works well. I added this in my delegate - which already has a custom `paint` method for other things and it does exactly what I want:

[image: Neat]

Neat.

Things start to go rogue when I want to decide what borders I actually draw. To do this, each item has a `BorderOption` property, which describes what borders should be draw. And my grid isn't 1px large anymore.

So what I decided to try out was the following:

```
painter->drawLine(option.rect.topLeft(), option.rect.topRight());
painter->drawLine(option.rect.bottomLeft(), option.rect.bottomRight());
```

Which should have the same result, right? Right? Well... no.

[image: Sadness]

It seems like two 1px-width lines are being drawn, one for each cell.

That *could* make sense, if the cells' rectangles didn't overlap. But we've seen before it is *not* the case, as the first example worked and produced rectangles of width 1px.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you draw the top and bottom borders for each row, you draw the same line twice: the bottom border of the first row is the top border of second row. If you consider that you have one pixel between each row, you will have a border 1 pixel larger

Comment: The thing is I shouldn't have one pixel between each row: the first version (which draws a rectangle directly) doesn't have the issue, and uses the same data as I do.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a misconception on the meaning of `option.rect`. It is really the rectangle of the item of the table. There is still a portion, a one pixel wide line, that does not belong to the `option.rect` of the item, but to the `QTreeView` itself.

This becomes more visible if you restrict the drawing to the allowed item portion by setting `setClipRect` and by making the lines distinguishable using different colors.

Try to experiment with the width of the drawn line and by enabling and disabling the clip rect. Maybe you need to draw outside of the allowed `option.rec`, but be aware that you have to consider also different drawings of `QTreeView` on different platforms, where the separating lines might be 0px wide or wider than just one pixel.

```
#pragma once

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QItemSelectionModel>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QDebug>

class MyDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
public:

    MyDelegate(QObject* parent=nullptr) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) { }
    void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const {

        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
        if (true) {
            painter->save();
            auto color=QColor::fromHsv((30*index.row() + 30 * index.column()) % 255, 255, 127);
            painter->setPen(QPen(color, 1, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::SquareCap, Qt::BevelJoin));
            painter->setClipRect(option.rect); // Rectangle of the item

            painter->drawLine(option.rect.topLeft(), option.rect.topRight());
            painter->drawLine(option.rect.bottomLeft(), option.rect.bottomRight());
            painter->restore();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to set **thickness** of the pen manually?

```
painter->setPen(QPen(QColor(255, 0, 0), 3, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::SquareCap, Qt::BevelJoin));
painter->drawLine(option.rect.topLeft(), option.rect.topRight());
painter->drawLine(option.rect.bottomLeft(), option.rect.bottomRight());
```

Here, I set the **thickness** to the **3px** for example!

Comment: Yes, I have, and it is not the problem here. Drawing only one of the two lines produces a 1px wide line.